# Configuring wireless router to give priority to particular computer

Tags: wireless-networking, router, qos

I have a DLINK DIR-651 and I'm wondering if it's possible to configure it so that one particular computer gets priority. In other words it gets more bandwidth. What would be the steps to take? I tried adding the computer to DMZ but speeds went way down. I don't care about security (through the router), the computer has it's own security software.

Comment: Are you willing to flash the firmware to OpenWRT?
http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dir-615

Comment: @Oxinabox sure why not

Comment: @Oxinabox you want to tell me how it's done?

Comment: I don't really know how (otherwise I would have answered).
What I do know it is it basically impossible unless you flash it to new firmware that supports it (cos i don't think the default DLink firmware supports it.)

Once you have a supporting OS you are going to hae to do something involving VLANs, and probably iptables.
and all this is way beyond me.